# Can I write an input element, what is posted (or getted) in every form?

Tags: forms, input

I have many different forms in my page, all of them reloads the same page, but there is one input, which is always needed for the page to run.
Can I somehow set an input to send with all the forms on the page?

```
<input type='hidden' id='user' name='user' value="<?php echo $user; ?>">
<input type='hidden' id='site' name='site' value="<?php echo $defaultsite; ?>">

<form action='main.php' method='post'>
<button class='button1'>Back</button>
</form>
<form action='over_store.php' method='post'>
<button class='button1'>Overstore</button>
</form>
<form action='avg_resources.php' method='post'>
<button class='button1'>Avarage stored value</button>
</form>
<form action='avg_decreases.php' method='post'>
<button class='button1'>Avarage product decreasing</button>
</form>
```

I know, I can add the 'site' and 'user' input to all the forms, but is there any siplier solution? Can I post those two inputs with all the forms?

Comment: Hi Maestro, could you give us a [example]?

Comment: Of course! Iedit my question.